# Docker Communication with the Outside World

Tags: docker, networking, amazon-ecs

I just wanted to ask some questions on Docker with AWS ECS.

I am running docker containers through the use of AWS ECS. I was wondering if docker has the ability to make and send requests to the outside world. For example:

Could I run a health check system that pings and checks if a docker container is healthy by receiving a response from the docker container(which is running on EC2)?

Also could I send data out of a docker container to a Application Load Balancer that would take the data and send it to wherever it needs to go?

In asking these questions I am trying to see if docker can communicate with the outside world, even after reading documentation on its isolated environment.
Thanks

Comment: In general, yes, containers can make outbound connections without special setup, even on setups like ECS or Kubernetes.  In an AWS environment this is subject to security group permissions.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me David. I assume they could receive inbound connections too because docker tasks have ENIs attached to them would this be correct?

Comment: Yes docker containers have standard networking support. They would only be of very limited use if they didn't. Docker containers running on ECS can both send and receive network traffic. Are you running into an actual problem or issue where your ECS containers can't access the network?

Comment: Hey Mark thank you for getting back to me, I was having intial issues with networking but I think this was more do to EC2 and IAM roles issues - I figured it out now. Thanks again!